# Is there any way for Python 3.0 Multiline Animation Control

Tags: python-3.x

I want to add animation in my module and for that multiple lines are to be controlled dynamically, but i can't find Right option for that.

Exact Info:

```
D:\Project> python download.py
Connection Established :)
Downloading 50/500 files...
                  .
    __            |\
 __/__\___________| \_
|   ___            ___`-.
|  /   \   10%    /   \  `-.
|_| (O) |________| (O) |____|
   \___/          \___/
```

After 50%

```
D:\Project> python download.py
Connection Established :)
Downloading 250/500 files...
                                                .
                                  __            |\
                               __/__\___________| \_
                              |   ___            ___`-.
                              |  /   \   50%    /   \  `-.
                              |_| (O) |________| (O) |____|
...............................  \___/          \___/
```

Comment: Hi @imLolman if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print a string at a certain screen position using:

```
sys.stdout.write("\x1b7\x1b[%d;%df%s\x1b8" % (row, col, text))
```

The following code will do the job:

```
import os, sys, time

def update_screen(done, total):
    percent = int((done/total)*100)
    x_location = (percent//2)+1
    sys.stdout.write("\x1b7\x1b[%d;%df%s\x1b8" % (2, 0, "Connection Established :)"))
    sys.stdout.write("\x1b7\x1b[%d;%df%s\x1b8" % (3, 0, "Downloading {0}/{1} files...".format(done, total)))
    sys.stdout.write("\x1b7\x1b[%d;%df%s\x1b8" % (4, x_location, "                   .          "))
    sys.stdout.write("\x1b7\x1b[%d;%df%s\x1b8" % (5, x_location, "     __            |\         "))
    sys.stdout.write("\x1b7\x1b[%d;%df%s\x1b8" % (6, x_location, "  __/__\___________| \_       "))
    sys.stdout.write("\x1b7\x1b[%d;%df%s\x1b8" % (7, x_location, " |   ___            ___`-.    "))
    sys.stdout.write("\x1b7\x1b[%d;%df%s\x1b8" % (8, x_location, " |  /   \          /   \  `-. "))
    sys.stdout.write("\x1b7\x1b[%d;%df%s\x1b8" % (9, x_location, " |_| (O) |________| (O) |____|"))
    sys.stdout.write("\x1b7\x1b[%d;%df%s\x1b8" % (10,x_location, ".   \___/          \___/      "))
    sys.stdout.write("\x1b7\x1b[%d;%df%s\x1b8" % (8, x_location+12, "{: 2d}%".format(percent)))
    sys.stdout.flush()

def main():
    os.system("clear")
    for i in range(500):
        update_screen(i, 500)
        time.sleep(0.2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This kind of does the job but this is not exactly I needed.